# Build Dynamic Substr

Tags: hive, hiveql, substr

I have a string as below and I want to use substring function in HIVE to look for request_id and extract its value.

http://www.mywebiste.com/first_page/4.0/US/en-US/USD/h_xp/139739685/2017-01-27/2017-02-03/room/room/room?rooms_left=0&mypage_ids=uk1_be8f79426367676762wfdef&q_datetime_utc=2016-10-12T03%3A44%3A18&guests=2&request_id=abcdefecf-bb52-42b7-

In the above line, I need to look for request_id and extract "abcdefecf-bb52-42b7-" as the ouput. Can you guys please share some ideas on acheiving this using SQL on HIVE

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_url` which is built-in in Hive

```
select parse_url(url, 'QUERY', 'request_id')
```